Chip Identification - TVS diodes
Can someone please confirm that these are bidirectional TVS diodes, I cannot find the datasheets for these anywhere, but they look to be them.




The first and the third diodes are Littelfuse parts, as can be seen by the spooning L and F-logo.

(source: https://m.littelfuse.com/~/media/electronics/datasheets/tvs_diodes/littelfuse_tvs_diode_smbj_datasheet.pdf.pdf) 


For the first one, WE means bidirectional 5V SMA size. Part number SMAJ5.0CA
(source: https://m.littelfuse.com/~/media/electronics/datasheets/tvs_diodes/littelfuse_tvs_diode_smaj_datasheet.pdf.pdf) 


For the third one,
CZ means bidirectional 51V in SMB size. Part number SMBJ51CA
EDIT: As noted by @Tim Willams, it has a cathode band, so it's not bidirectional, it's unidirectional and that would be SMAJ51A - 51V unidirectional SMA.
(source SMB: https://m.littelfuse.com/~/media/electronics/datasheets/tvs_diodes/littelfuse_tvs_diode_smbj_datasheet.pdf.pdf) 
(source SMA: https://m.littelfuse.com/~/media/electronics/datasheets/tvs_diodes/littelfuse_tvs_diode_smaj_datasheet.pdf.pdf)


The second one is a Diodes Inc part

(source: https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/SMAJ5.0CA-SMAJ200CA.pdf)
VK means Bidirectional 30V in SMA size. Part number SMAJ30CA
(Source: https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/SMAJ5.0CA-SMAJ200CA.pdf)

I think they're all SMA, in which case the 3rd is SMAJ51A. It has a line so is unidirectional.

@TimWilliams Yeah you're right. Bugger. I had a caveat about the question not giving any info on case size in my first version of the answer. And then I removed it because I assumed the manufacturers used unique codes across all sizes. I'll revisit datasheets and edit it in.
